# Icon image "error java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: java, image, icons

Well, I'm trying to set up my icon image, and I keep getting this error....

Code:

```
public static void browser(){
        Image myicon = null;
        myicon.equals("images/icon.gif");
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Kloke - Become invisable.");
        frame.setSize(350, 100);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setIconImage(myicon);
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at web.browser(web.java:14)
        at Checkupdate.main(Checkupdate.java:102)
```

PS. I am new to java, so feel free to treat me as if I have no idea what I am doing(PSS Line 14 is where I initialize the 'myicon' variable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempting to call *any* instance method on an object that has not been instantiated will cause a `NullPointerException`. You need to instantiate `myicon`

```
Image myicon = ImageIO.read(new File("images/icon.gif"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here `Image myicon = null;
        myicon.equals("images/icon.gif");`
You are setting myicon to null and comparing, so compiler is throwing NullPointerException